# How to generate a JSON file to preload and import to coreData?

Tags: ios, json, csv, core-data

I am following a popular tutorial on raywenderlich.com to preload core data.
This is my JSON file:

```
[
{
    "countDescription": "###",
    "countId": "###",
    "states": [
        {
            "stateDesc": "###",
            "stateId": "###",
            "cities": [
                {
                    "cityDescription": "###",
                    "cityId": "###",
                    "destinations": [
                        {
                            "destDescription": "###",
                            "destId": "###"
                        },
                        {
                            "destDescription": "###",
                            "destId": "###"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "cityDescription": "###",
                    "cityId": "###",
                    "destinations": [
                        {
                            "destDescription": "###",
                            "destId": "###"
                        },
                        {
                            "destDescription": "###",
                            "destId": "###"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "stateDesc": "###",
            "stateId": "###",
            "cities": [
                {
                    "cityDescription": "###",
                    "cityId": "###",
                    "destinations": [
                        {
                            "destDescription": "###",
                            "destId": "###"
                        },
                        {
                            "destDescription": "###",
                            "destId": "###"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "countDescription": "###",
    "countId": "###",
    "states": [
        {
            "stateDesc": "###",
            "stateId": "###",
            "cities": [
                {
                    "cityDescription": "###",
                    "cityId": "###",
                    "destinations": [
                        {
                            "destDescription": "###",
                            "destId": "###"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

My question is how can I do this in excel so I can then save it as a CSV file and use this [converter](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm) to get my JSON.

In the converter website I used the JSON-to-CSV option, but the generated CSV file only gives me the columns for the entity Country and then everything else for each row is in the next column and the names of the other attributes disappear.

If I use this other [source](https://json-csv.com/) then is wonderful, it looks exactly like what I think I want:

```
    "countDescription","countId","states__stateDesc","states__stateId","states__cities__cityDescription","states__cities__cityId","states__cities__destinations__destDescription","states__cities__destinations__destId"
"###","###","###","###","###","###","###","###"
"","","","","","","###","###"
"","","","","###","###","###","###"
"","","","","","","###","###"
"","","###","###","###","###","###","###"
"","","","","","","###","###"
"###","###","###","###","###","###","###","###"
```

But as soon as I make changes to the table and then proceed to save it as a CSV file the format is different, what gives?

English is my second language, I hope my question is not too difficult to understand, also if you guys don't mind me asking, is it correct to go one-to-many to one-to-many to one-to-many for the data model? I did managed to preload the JSON file to core data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is much easier to just quickly write your own parser and parse the CSV file. At least that is my workflow and it as proven to be very efficient. Read in the file as a string, separate into an array divided by `\n`, loop through the lines, for each line loop through the fields to construct a dictionary using the column headings as keys.

Then use the `NSJSONSerialization` class methods to generate your JSON data (tip: use the `.PrettyPrinted` option for readability). You can then generate a `String` from the data with `String(data:encoding:)` and save that to a file (or just dump it to the console and copy-paste).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mundi, I am a beginner and was hoping for a quick solution but I need to do more research. I will try [link](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) and come back with more questions I'm sure. Thanks again.